# How to compare two tables for data existence and set the color in the retrieved data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have two tables where one contains different jobs (`joblist`) and the other is (`savedjobs`) which stores the copy of that particular job from `joblist`. It is something like bookmarking the job for later use.

If I display all the jobs in the main screen I must see the saved jobs with a highlight saying that it is saved.

I tried like this:

```
{joblists &&
  joblists.map(joblist => {
    {
      resultJobs &&
        resultJobs.map(job => {
          if (joblist.id === job.id)
            return (
              <i
                id="heart"
                name={joblist.id}
                className="fas fa-heart float-right pr-4 text-danger"
                onClick={this.saveJob1}
              />
            );
        });
    }
  })
}
```

But what if there is no saved jobs? Can someone help?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to render all the elements in the `joblist` array, but highlight the element in some way if the element also is present in the `savedjobs` array?

Comment: Yes i would like to have `<i onClick={this.saveJob} className = "fas fa-heart text-danger "></i>` if the data is present in the savedjobs table and if not `<i onClick={this.saveJob} className = "far fa-heart text-primary "></i>`

Comment: Cannot understand why you are mapping twice.. you can simply iterate through the jobs and check if the job is in your saved job list as well. If yes apply your custom styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

[Code SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lp9rz9k3nq)

[image]

```
const jobList = ['Job A', 'Job B', 'Job C', 'Job D', 'Job E']
const savedJobs = ['Job C', 'Job D', 'Job E']


function App() {

  const resultJobs = jobList.map((job,index) => 
    <li key={index}>
      {job}
      {savedJobs.includes(job) ? 
        <React.Fragment>
          <span>---</span>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} style={{color:'red'}}/>
        </React.Fragment>
        : ''}
    </li>
  );


  return (
    <ul>
      {resultJobs}
    </ul>

  );
}
```